# Increase height of a particular nav nav-tabs li

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to increase the height of a particular bootstrap nav nav-tabs li element, trying to put a style of height on the li element makes the whole ul element increase as illustrated in the image below.
[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9toA.png)

I tried :

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<li>
<a>Tab 1 </a>
</li>
<li class="active">
<a>Tab 2 </a>
</li>
<li>
<a>Tab 3 </a>
</li>
</ul>
```

To:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<li>
<a>Tab 1 </a>
</li>
<li class="active" style="height:80px;">
<a>Tab 2 </a>
</li>
<li>
<a>Tab 3 </a>
</li>
</ul>
```

I want it to look like this image below
[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fc8Sz.png)

Comment: What've you tried, what didn't work. Provide relevant css / html

Answer (score 0):

- Try with !important

  **style="height:80px !important;**

---

Comment: same result, pushes it downwards not upwards